# How to get the real time of driving throw google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing a delivery android app, i let the user to input 2 points then i draw the polygon after hitting a request to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/` this seems fine and it produces json like this part

```
"steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "1 m",
                        "value" : 0
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 0
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.2032168,
                        "lng" : 35.4687987
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Head on \u003cb\u003eKings Hwy.\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eRoute 35\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "cajwD_onwE"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.2032168,
                        "lng" : 35.4687987
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
```

well, it seems all good so far, my problem is how to get the real time? i mean when the driver starts driving i need to update my estimation time based on car speed,
it's hard to make an httprequest every 5 seconds, because the json file will need a lot of calculation as you see json file is just 5% of the whole json response regardless to the internet speed,they all need a huge time and it will drain the battery, is there a way to pull the time direct for the original google map ?

Comment: I'm afraid Google Maps API Terms of Service prohibit using the API for real-time navigation. Have a look at the explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807131/5140781

Comment: thank you for your comment, how "wase" app is running then?

Comment: [Waze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waze) belongs to Google, they can use internal APIs not available publicly.

Comment: got it thank you :)